# Maximum duration between candidate backing and inclusion

Tags: parachain, consensus

For our BEEFY-powered bridge, we need to determine the relay chain block in which a finalized parachain header was included. It seems this happens roughly 2-3 blocks after the relay chain block which backed the candidate.

I was wondering if there is some limit on the maximum block gap between backing and inclusion, before the process times out? For example, could the candidate ever be included like 20 blocks after it was backed?

Knowing this limit if there is one would help improve our code for determining the inclusion block number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longest any backed block candidate is considered for availability/inclusion is 4 blocks. It is dropped on the 4th block after the block on which availability distribution efforts started.